# Make simple GLFW compiling with MinGW and cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, glfw, clion

I'm using cmake (clion embedded) and mingw to compile simple glfw code:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(hw)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
find_library(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GLFW_LIBRARY_DIRS})
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(hw ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(hw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} )
```

I've included downloaded glfw for win64 files:

- GLFW folder to C:\MinGW\include
- lib-mingw folder content to C:\MinGW\lib

And I get following error

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 1.1.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\...\.clion11\system\cmake\generated\82abf0c4\82abf0c4\Debug --target all -- -j 2
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 1.1.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -HC:\Users\...\ClionProjects\hw -BC:\Users\...\.clion11\system\cmake\generated\82abf0c4\82abf0c4\Debug --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 1.1.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start C:\Users\...\.clion11\system\cmake\generated\82abf0c4\82abf0c4\Debug\CMakeFiles C:\Users\...\.clion11\system\cmake\generated\82abf0c4\82abf0c4\Debug\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/.../.clion11/system/cmake/generated/82abf0c4/82abf0c4/Debug'
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\hw.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/hw.dir/depend
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/.../.clion11/system/cmake/generated/82abf0c4/82abf0c4/Debug'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 1.1.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\...\ClionProjects\hw C:\Users\...\ClionProjects\hw C:\Users\...\.clion11\system\cmake\generated\82abf0c4\82abf0c4\Debug C:\Users\...\.clion11\system\cmake\generated\82abf0c4\82abf0c4\Debug C:\Users\...\.clion11\system\cmake\generated\82abf0c4\82abf0c4\Debug\CMakeFiles\hw.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/.../.clion11/system/cmake/generated/82abf0c4/82abf0c4/Debug'
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\hw.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/hw.dir/build
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/.../.clion11/system/cmake/generated/82abf0c4/82abf0c4/Debug'
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable hw.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 1.1.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\hw.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 1.1.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\hw.dir/objects.a
C:\MinGW\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\hw.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\hw.dir\objects1.rsp
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe   -std=c++11 -g   -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\hw.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o hw.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libhw.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\hw.dir\linklibs.rsp
CMakeFiles\hw.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
C:/Users/.../ClionProjects/hw/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `glfwInit'
C:/Users/.../ClionProjects/hw/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
C:/Users/.../ClionProjects/hw/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
C:/Users/.../ClionProjects/hw/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
C:/Users/.../ClionProjects/hw/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [hw.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hw.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\hw.dir\build.make:98: recipe for target 'hw.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/.../.clion11/system/cmake/generated/82abf0c4/82abf0c4/Debug'
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:69: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/hw.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/.../.clion11/system/cmake/generated/82abf0c4/82abf0c4/Debug'
Makefile:85: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is my pretty first program c++ program with cmake and mingw, so I cant underestand what I have to do to make it just compile

Comment: You're not linking to `GLFW`. Try asking your local CMake wizard for help

Comment: Two things to check: did cmake really find GLFW?  ( to check,  make it print the library path,  or use make VERBOSE=1). Second thing is to have a g++ version that matches the one that was used to compile GLFW.

Comment: @BrunoLevy I've updated question and include verbose output. What can be the reason to not find GLFW? I've mention path where I copy files in question. Should I put it somewhere else?

Comment: It seems that GLFW is not linked (in the log, there should be an argument like -lGLFW in the last g++.exe command). To figure-out what's happening, you can first try adding in your CMakeFile.txt the following line: message(STATUS GLFW_LIBRARY_DIRS=${GLFW_LIBRARY_DIRS} GLFW_LIBRARIES=${GLFW_LIBRARIES}). I suspect that find_library() does not do the job correctly (but at least the compiler finds the headers, therefore ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS}$ is probably correct (you can also check with message()). What you can try is directly adding -L and -l directives to CMake's LINK_FLAG variable.